# (PowerPc) Understanding assembly code – "some_label: .long some_label"

Tags: assembly, powerpc

I just got confused with this piece of assembly code:

`# in .data section`

`off_832FE694: .long off_832FE694`

Is it an address that holds an address to itself?

Comment: Yup, looks that way.

Comment: The equivalent in C would be `void * off_832FE694 = &off_832FE694;`.